# How do companies in US count part time (20 hrs per week) work towards full-time work experience

Tags: resume, work-experience, part-time

Last year while doing my graduate studies, I worked for 6-months part time (20 hrs/week).

My question is when quoting total work experience in US either on my resume or to a hiring manager, how should I count the part time work experience ? For example can I quote my 6-months part time work experience as 3-months full-time work experience ?

How do companies count part time work experience when considering total full-time work experience of a candidate ?

Comment: On your resume, just state exactly what it is e.g. **Jan - June 2020 (Part Time): ferret wrangler**. Hiring managers can then choose how they want to count it.

Comment: "when quoting total work experience" <- why do you want to do this at all?

Comment: Many job application forms ask to give total  work experience. What to mention there ?

Comment: I have never seen that on a form. Which industry is this in?

Comment: @PhilipKendall: This is somewhat common for large companies with automated application processes. I've seen this for software engineering jobs in Europe.

Comment: You worked for 6 months, your experience is 6 months. Doesn't matter if it was full or part time, unless they specifically state that these details are needed in the application.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the sake of putting in an answer,

1. You ***definitely would not*** "convert" it to fulltime.  Whatever you do, don't do that.  (So in the example, **absolutely do not** say "3 months fulltime".)
2. You can simply write "1/2020 - 6/2020: ferret wrangler.  Half-time position."
3. And if you *don't mention* at this point that it was half-time, really that's not "bad" or "wrong"  (particularly if you have a long list). It's only a summary for now.

But sure, simply "2" is the answer.

> How do companies count part time work experience when considering total full-time work experience of a candidate ?

They see it as strictly a separate concept.

Answer (score 2):

Don't overthink it.  If you worked part time for a year, put in "1 year".  The end game is to be able to speak credibly about your experience in an interview.  Job reqs that ask for "X years of experience" have cracks in them, for example asking for 10 yrs of experience with XYZ when XYZ was invented 5 years ago.

Again, don't overthink this stuff.